# GraalVM in docker : Fatal error reported via JNI: Could not allocate set properties

Tags: java, docker, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I am trying to containerize my spring application with graalVM, but when the application is containerized, I cannot generate a PDF in my application.
The API works as long as I don't generate pdf.

When my application runs locally, the PDF is generated.
When my application is compiled natively and execute, the PDF is generated.
When my application is compiled from a containerized environment, for example the image container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/jdk:17, when I try to generate a pdf, the pdf will not be generated, and I have this error :

> Fatal error reported via JNI: Could not allocate set properties

stacktrace:
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnP32.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkIpp.png)

In my spring application I use a library to generate PDFs: openhtml, version 1.0.10

For native compilation, I use the
`mvn -Pnative native:compile` 
command, although
`mvn package -Pnative` 
works too.
These commands when executed locally generate a target folder, with an app.exe file inside allowing me to launch my native application
When these commands are executed from a container, it is an app file, without .exe extension

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bouvet</groupId>
    <artifactId>location-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>location-manager</name>
    <description>Location Manager</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <openhtml.version>1.0.10</openhtml.version>
        <start-class>com.bouvet.locationmanager.LocationManagerApplication</start-class>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf-toolbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-core</artifactId>
            <version>${openhtml.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>${openhtml.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openhtmltopdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>openhtmltopdf-java2d</artifactId>
            <version>${openhtml.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.28</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <imageName>app</imageName>
                            <mainClass>com.bouvet.locationmanager.LocationManagerApplication</mainClass>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <buildArgs>
                                        <arg>--static</arg>
                                        <arg>--no-fallback</arg>
                                        <arg>-H:IncludeResources=".*"</arg>
                                        <arg>-H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=META-INF/native-image/</arg>
                                        <arg>-H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC</arg>
                                        <arg>-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces</arg>
                                    </buildArgs>
                                </configuration>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:17-ol8
WORKDIR /build
COPY . /build
RUN rm -rf /build/target
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' mvnw
RUN ./mvnw -Pnative native:compile
EXPOSE 80
ENV SERVER_PORT=80
ENTRYPOINT ["/build/target/app"]
```

To be compliant with librairies, i have already generate files with an agent with this command :

`java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image -jar location-manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Without this files, it is impossible to generate PDF in local environnement:
[META-INF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNPQ.png)

I am on a Windows 11 environment

`native-image --version`

> native-image 21.0.1 2023-10-17
> GraalVM Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
> Oracle GraalVM VM Substrate 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12, serial gc, compressed references)

`java --version`

> java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)

Does anyone have any leads please ?

I have try this images :

- ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol8-java17-22.3.3
- ghcr.io/graalvm/native-image:ol9-java17
- ghcr.io/graalvm/jdk-community:17-ol9
- ubuntu:jammy
- container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:17-ol8
- container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/native-image:21-ol8
- container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/jdk:17
- scratch

Comment: Since it works without containers when using 21, you probably want to use 21 also for the container (not 17). Another issue you might have is running the agent on windows but building the image on linux (in the container). You might want to make sure you run the agent on the same JDK version (21) and OS (linux) as the ones used for building the image.